# Intermittent `Error: cannot open display: localhost:10.0` with Vagrant

Tags: 12.04, xorg, ssh, vagrant

I've set up a Vagrant VM with X forwarding.  I'm connecting to it with the following command (to improve X performance):

```
ssh -c arcfour,blowfish-cbc -XC vagrant@VM-NAME
```

This works fine; I log into the VM and whenever I launch an X Windows application it is rendered in my local X client.

However, after around 15 - 30 minutes use, I start getting the following error when launching X Windows applications:

```
vagrant@VM-NAME:~/$ firefox
Error: cannot open display: localhost:10.0
```

This persists until I disconnect my SSH connection and reconnect.  Oddly, any X Windows applications I've already launched keep running normally.

The error happens regardless of whether I'm using tmux or not.  My system details are as follows:

*Host*

```
Mac OS X 10.7.5
VirtualBox 4.2.6 r82870
```

*Client*

```
Ubuntu 12.04 (precise)
Kernel 3.2.0-35-generic (#55-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 5 17:42:16 UTC 2012)
Xorg 1.11.3 (29 August 2012  12:12:33AM)
```

I've installed the full ubuntu-desktop package on the VM.

Any ideas on how to fix this?  I've found plenty of documentation and issue reports surrounding X forwarding not working *at all*, but nothing relating to eventual failure.

N.B: I have upgraded my SSH client and XQuartz to the very latest versions but the problem persists.  It does *not* happen, however, if I use the regular `vagrant ssh` command to connect to the VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have answered the related question over on stack exchange:

[Intermittent `Error: cannot open display: localhost:10.0` with Vagrant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14206071/intermittent-error-cannot-open-display-localhost10-0-with-vagrant/14228815)

In short, use -Y in the ssh config and you'll be ok.